# Unobtrusive JS Framework for Skinning

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript, skinning

Just before re-inventing the wheel - I wonder if there's a lightweight/standalone JS framework for styling web apps (perhaps LESS based)?

Ideally I'd like to be able to mark certain regions of my layout as 'stylable', give them data-style-name or use any other 'unobtrusive' approach, create my skins and then be able to call: style.switch({skinName: "paleBlue"});

Has anyone came across with something like that? I'm new to JS dev, so beg your pardon if it's been asked already.

Comment: Something like jQuery UI thememroller perhaps ? http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ (although thats a whole page)

Comment: Not what I would call lightweight or standalone... Perhaps you want to take a look at yarnify https://github.com/substack/yarnify

Comment: @ManseUK something like that, but I'd like it to be lighter and be standalone ideally.